# Value of the J Invariant at $\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2}$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, modular-forms

For a while I've wanted to be able to show why $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx 744+640320^3$, but I have no idea how to show that $j(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2})=-640320^3$. 
I considered using the fact that $\mid \eta(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163})}{2})\mid^{4}=\frac{1}{326\pi}\prod_{n=1}^{162}\Gamma({\frac{n}{163}} )^{(\frac{n}{163})}$ (exponent is the legendre symbol) but I'd also need $\eta(\sqrt{-163})$ and also I have no idea how the simplification would work out. I've seen values of J being related to roots of polynomials and was wondering if that would be the easiest way to compute it. If anyone could explain methods that could be used to compute it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Adjoining $\alpha = j(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2})$ to $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-163})$ gives its Hilbert class field, which is itself. Hence $\alpha\in K$, since $\alpha$ is real and an algebraic integer, $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$, so you can just numerically compute $\alpha$ to a desired accuracy.

Comment: @pisco Thanks for your answer! Is the fact that J at that number is an integer the only way to show the value is -640320^3? Are there any other ways to directly get that value without using numerical computation?

Comment: You can see this https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2976

Comment: The j invariant is related to the Ramanujan class invariant $G$ via $j=-\dfrac{27G^{48}}{(G^{24}-4)^3}$ but the calculation of $G$ and further computation of $j$ is difficult at least via pen and paper.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh is that $G=G_{163}$?

Comment: Yes! Let $n>0$ be rational then Ramanujan defines $$G_n=2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1+q^{2k-1}),\,q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}$$ and then $$j_n=-\frac{27G_n^{48}}{(G_n^{24}-4)^3}$$ The value you seek is $j_{163} $.

Comment: Btw we have $$G_{163}=\frac{6+\sqrt[3]{135-3\sqrt{489}}+\sqrt[3]{135+3\sqrt{489}}}{3\sqrt[4]{2}}$$

Comment: If you are interested in elliptic curves, a good explanation of "the almost integer" can be found in chapter 2 of Silverman's "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", along with the beautiful theory of complex multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$j(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2})=-640320^3$

$j(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2})=-2^{15}*J_{163}^{3}$

$j^{1/3}=-2^{5}*J=-2^{5}\big(\frac{G^{8}}{8}-\frac{1}{2G^{16}}\big)$.

$J=\frac{G^{8}}{8}-\frac{1}{2G^{16}}$

is the $J$
of Ramanujan

$\frac{4-G^{24}}{8G^{16}}=-20010$

E pertanto $G_{163}$ is that of Paramanand Singh.